# How do I get my sidebar to float to the right?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

In Wordpress I've got a sidebar that has a WooCommerce widget within it. I'm trying to get it to float to the right which works fine with the `float: right` statement, but because I want the sidebar to scroll along with the page I use the `position: fixed` statement, but that pulls it to the left automatically.

What do I need to add to make the sidebar keep to the right?

P.S. when looking at the HTML, Javascript/PHP note that it's Wordpress/Woocommerce native commands.

CSS:

```
#secondary {
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 91px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

HTML:

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

PHP/Javascript:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>

<ul class="cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo $args['list_class']; ?>">

    <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

        <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {

                    $product_name  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $thumbnail     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                            '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                            esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                            esc_attr( $product_id ),
                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                        ), $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                        <?php if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) : ?>
                            <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) ); ?>">
                                <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <li class="empty"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></li>

    <?php endif; ?>

</ul><!-- end product list -->

<?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

    <p class="total"><strong><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

    <p class="buttons">
        <!-- <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="button wc-forward"><?php _e( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a> -->
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="btn btn-default" id="minicart-btn"><?php _e( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
    </p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the sidebar to be fixed to the right of the page, you can use the `right` property along with your fixed positioning:

```
right: 0px;
```

`float` will not work with a `fixed` element.

Answer (score 2):

Position fixed and float right can't be used together. Use right: 0 to make fixed element to stay at right side.

Answer (score 0):

you should firsr konw the BFC in CSS.
you can got the information of BFC below
[CSS 101: Block Formatting Contexts](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/)